# Python pip install jira 1.0.10.tar.gz gives “Command ”python setup.py egg_info“ failed with error code 1”

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have been trying to install jira 1.0.10.tar.gz packages with pip.I have installed python 3.6 on my system. My command line throws me this error though:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\manmohit
.kaur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z0dmal3l-build\
```

Please find below the logs

```
D:\cucumber\Drivers\Drivers>pip3 install jira-1.0.10.tar.gz
Processing d:\cucumber\drivers\drivers\jira-1.0.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytest-runner/: [Errno 1100
2] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo
 failed -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pytest-runner
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\manmohit.kaur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z0dmal3l-build\setup.p
y", line 37, in <module>
        test_suite='tests')
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108,
 in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist
.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist
.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_
_init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_
_init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_
_init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist
.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comm
and\easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Re
quirement.parse('pytest-runner')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\manmohit
.kaur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z0dmal3l-build\
```

**Please find below logs for "pip install jira"**

```
D:\cucumber\Drivers\Drivers>pip install jira-1.0.10.tar.gz
Processing d:\cucumber\drivers\drivers\jira-1.0.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytest-runner/: [Errno 1100
2] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo
 failed -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pytest-runner
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\manmohit.kaur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-zui7xx58-build\setup.p
y", line 37, in <module>
        test_suite='tests')
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108,
 in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist
.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist
.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_
_init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_
_init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_
_init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist
.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comm
and\easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Re
quirement.parse('pytest-runner')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\manmohit
.kaur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-zui7xx58-build\
```

**D:\cucumber\Drivers\Drivers>pip install jira**

```
Collecting jira
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03E76350>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03E760D0>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03E76090>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03E76150>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03E760B0>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/jira/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jira (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for jira
```

Comment: is that the only error?

Comment: can you paste entire trace?

Comment: Hi I have paste the complete logs.Please check

Comment: why not use just "pip install jira"?

Comment: I tried with "pip install jira".. even this is not working

Comment: do you have same error?

Comment: When I Tried with "pip install jira" --> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\manmohit
.kaur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-zui7xx58-build\

Comment: maybe you can post the stacktrace as well for "pip install jira"

Comment: are you interested on a specific version? else just put "pip install jira" not "pip install jira-1.0.10.tar.gz"

Comment: I have posted the logs for pip.Please check

Comment: just use "pip install jira" without the version and see if the same error is encountered

Comment: I need to install this jira -1.0.10.tar.gz version

Comment: I have posted the error coming for "pip install jira"

Comment: you dont need to add the extension
try
`pip install jira==1.0.10`

Comment: also 1.0.10 version of jira **doesnt support `python 3.6`**

Comment: Which python version i need to install?

Comment: It would be safe to use python 3.0

Answer (score 0):

To install `jira 1.0.10` you need to mention the version while installing as follows

`pip install jira==1.0.10`

As you mentioned, you are using `python 3.6`, and the [pypi page of jira 1.0.10](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira/) says that it requires some components of python like `argeparse` and `ordereddict` to have python version less than `3.2` and `3.1` respectively.

So its safe to assume that `jira 1.0.10` is not compatible with `python 3.6`

Use jira 1.0.10, you will need to use python version less than 3.1.

So it would be safe to use python 3.0

Comment: Ok I’ll install python version less thn 3.1 and will try again

Comment: Can you add the stack trace

Comment: On my colleague's system its working with Python 3.6 only.

Comment: Using a clean virtual environment might help!